# Killing sub process when it is expecting input

Tags: java, processbuilder

```
public static int launch(String pathTojar ,String params) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];      
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", pathTojar, "L", "C", params);
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    processBuilder.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    //kill child process when parent process dies
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(process::destroyForcibly));
    InputStream in = process.getInputStream();

    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {
            int r = 0;
            try {
                r = in.read(buffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (r <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.write(buffer, 0, r);
        }});
        t.start();

    return process.waitFor();
}
```

the child process is only exiting on `CTRL+C` (child's asking user 'if user want to continue next cycle' infinitely ) and that kills parent process(current thread). How to kill child process when it displays a question (i.e. expecting input) without killing parent.

thanks in advance..

Comment: Have your tried to redirect the ouput of the child preocess to your application, and to kill the child process (interrupt the thread), when the question, you mentioned, occurs?

Comment: yes I have tried that marvin but  it didnt work for me..